# Understanding sign and overflow flag in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

This question is about the `cmp` instruction in assembly. I cannot understand how my books reasoning regarding the `SF` and `OF` flags.

```
 cmp vleft, vright
```

According to my book: For signed integers, there are three flags that are important: the zero `(ZF)` flag, the overflow `(OF)` flag and the sign `(SF)` flag. The overflow flag is set if the result of an operation overflows (or underflows). The sign flag is set if the result of an operation is negative. If `vleft = vright`, the `ZF` is set (just as for unsigned integers). If `vleft > vright`, `ZF` is unset and `SF = OF`. If `vleft < vright`, `ZF` is unset and `SF != OF`. Do not forget that other instructions can also change the FLAGS register, not just `CMP`.

First, let's consider the `vleft > vright` case. My book says the following:

> *Why does SF = OF if vleft > vright? If there is no overflow, then the difference will have the correct value and must be non-negative. Thus,
>   SF = OF = 0. However, if there is an overflow, the difference will not
>   have the correct value (and in fact will be negative). Thus, SF = OF =
>   1.*

The first part i understand that `SF = OF = 0`. It could for example be:

`0111 - 0101 = 0111 + 1010 + 1 = 10010 = 7 - 5 = 2`

This would not set the `OF` or `SF` flag.

The case could also be:

`1100 - 0101 = 1100 + 1010 + 1 = 10111 = -4 - 5 = 7 (-9 if we had more bits)`

This would not set the `SF` flag (since the answer is the positive 7) but would set `OF = 1`, thus `SF != OF`. This clearly goes against the explanation of my book which says they should be equal.

What am I missing here?

Thank you!

Comment: It's weird to talk about assembly and processor details such as flags and such *without* mentioning which CPU you're talking about. There are a few, you know.

Comment: Sorry about that, but this should be X86 (80386 and later) processors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are gonna bang your head on the wall, sorry about that :)

In your example, **-4 is not greater than 5**! So yeah, `OF` will be `1` and `SF` will be `0`, and they won't be equal, and that means -4 is less than 5, and that's correct.

To illustrate the `SF = OF = 1` case reverse the operands: check if `5 > -4` by doing

`5 - (-4) = 5 + 4 = 1001b = -7`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Very helpful! Will stop banging my head against the wall now :)

Comment: If you have some time can you please check out my previous (similar) question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14101058/assembly-comparison-flags-understanding? It would be very nice to get some more insight into that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Your book is right about OF== (SF!=CF) when both operands have the same sign. When the operands are of different sign, there can be no OF.

However, in RTL level, the OF flag is most often computed as difference of carry_in != carry_out calculated at the sign bit.

```
i.e. for 1100-0101 = 1100+1010+1
bit position 0:  c_in=c_0= 1, a_0 = 0, b_0 = 0;  result=1, c_out=0
             1:  c_in=c_1= 0, a_1 = 0, b_1 = 1;  result=1, c_out=0
             2:  c_in=c_2= 0, a_2 = 1, b_2 = 0;  result=1, c_out=0
             3:  c_in=c_3= 0, a_3 = 1, b_3 = 1;  result=0, c_out=1
```

Here c_in_3 != c_out_3, which means an overflow.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Aki. I understand why there is an overflow in the example you gave and how to check for it using the msb. But I cannot understand why the SF flag is set to 1. The result is as you wrote it 0111, which is positive and hence SF should be set to 0? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, SF will take the copy of the MSB. Also now I see, why the "same sign" rule is actually bad, as the rule has to be inverted for subtraction. Adding same signed variables can lead to OF, as well as subtracting different signed variables.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I am afraid i still don't understand this 100%, can you please explain to me the case (and why) when SF and OF are both == 1 and when vleft > vright? Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: (clarification) In your example you have a SF of 0 and an OF of 1 but still the vleft>vright. According to my book this should not be possible since if vleft>vright SF & OF should be 1 or both should be 0.